# CakePHP Media Plugin save images in subfolder of filter directories

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm wondering if the following is possible in the CakePHP Media Plugin (using the latest version).

I want my cropped images in this structure, in a subdirectory matching the first character of the name of the product that the image is associated with (using the monolithic Attachment model).

MEDIA_FILTER is a constant so you can't change it on the fly.  Is there a way to force the Media plugin to use these folders?  Preferably without altering the plugin?

```
/app/webroot/files/filter/large/img/a/image.jpg
/app/webroot/files/filter/large/img/b/image2.jpg
/app/webroot/files/filter/medium/img/a/image.jpg
/app/webroot/files/filter/medium/img/b/image2.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out after a bit of trial and error.

```
    $dir = 'my_directory';
    $this->Behaviors->load('Media.Transfer',
        array(
            'transferDirectory' => MEDIA_TRANSFER . $dir . DS
        )
    );
```

This sets the directory images are saved into on the fly, and works for the "filter" directories too (ie where images get saved after resizing).